# How to receive cell broadcast messages ?

Tags: android, sony, sony-xperia

I have an Xperia ZL (firmware 10.3.1.A.0.244).

On my other Sony Ericsson phones I was able to receive cell broadcast messages from my operator about tariff zones; they were shown on screen like this :

[image: here]

Is it possible to receive such messages on an Xperia ZL ?

I set "Allow push messages" from "Push settings" of "Messaging" Settings menu, but I have no messages anywhere on the screen.

I did small searches on the Internet, and got some info :

1. [CellBroadcastReceiver exists in AOSP](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/CellBroadcastReceiver/).
2. Some people extracted [CellBroadcastReceiver.apk](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1946265) from the Nexus firmware.
3. CyanogenMod has CellBroadcastReceiver.apk and Phone.apk for [CellBroadcast](https://jira.cyanogenmod.org/browse/CYAN-186) receive.

So it is theoretically possible to receive cell broadcast messages.
It would be good if Sony supported receiving CellBroadcast messages in newer (for example, Android 4.3) firmwares.